# My custom form is not exported with my solution CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have created in my unmanaged solution a new form to Contact entity. I exported my solution as managed (after publishing) and when i import it to my test enviroment the form is not appear. In the customization.xml file there is not any line about my new form. Why the form cannot be included to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my roblem deleting the form and creating it again. Now all is ok